# How to make selenium driver wait for certain cases?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have a selenium script that should find an element and click on it after a process is done

Process takes 3 seconds for most of the cases, so used:

```
time.sleep(3) / driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.find_element_by_id('id').click()
```

In few cases same process takes 6 seconds to complete. so getting this

error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

How to use try else except here :

```
try : 
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_id('id').click()

else : 
    time.sleep(6)
    driver.find_element_by_id('id').click()
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using hard wait for the elements, you can induce webdriver wait for the elements like:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).click()
```

And you have to add the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: you can use with try if needed:

try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "id"))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    print("there's no element")

Answer (score -1):

Why can't you go for implicity wait for 6 seconds? if elements available in 3 seconds then no issue, it will handle right? if not it will wait until 6 seconds.

Comment: tried this driver.implicitly_wait(100) . but app is still searching for id even after loading

Comment: If he's already waiting for 30s, how is waiting for *less* time going to solve the issue?

Comment: @JeffC i mean to say if we give max as 6 sec it will work for 6sec as well as 3 sec in implicity wait. if he need 30 sec or any other no can use it.

Comment: I think you need to read the question again. The question clearly states that he used 30s of implicit wait and it didn't work. Your answer with a shorter wait time will not work.